# Почему вылетает java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed content type: application/json)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

Пытаюсь получить данные из БД, но не вылетает ошибка :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed content type: application/json).
 Класс данных, в который должен вкачаться List со всеми объектами из БД:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
@SerializedName("Data")
protected T data;
public T getData() { return data;}
```

Часть интерфейса, отвечающая за получение этого Листа (интерфейс, указанный для создания Retrofit) :

```
@Headers({"Authorization: Basic NTlkY2M1YzVhNGJlMjA1ODZkMsYwZTgzOjE2NWM2MjNhNDI=",
            "X-Api-Factory-Application-Id: 59dgc5c5a4be20586d260e83",
            "Content-Type: application/json)"})
    @GET("db/Usage")
    Observable<BaseResponse<List<Usage>>> getUsageResponse();
```

В постмане работает.
Создание ретрофита:

```
protected UsageDBInterface restService;

    protected Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(this.BASE_URL)
            .client(provideClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    protected OkHttpClient provideClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .build();
    }

    protected UsageDBInterface getRestService(){
        if (restService==null) restService = retrofit.create(UsageDBInterface.class);
        return restService;
    }
```

Метод, обеспечивающий доступ приложения к слою данных:  public ArrayList getCategoryUsageList() {

```
 Observable<ArrayList<Usage>> observableList;
    ArrayList<Usage> result = new ArrayList<>();
    restService.getUsageResponse().map(BaseResponse::getData)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(resultList->{
                result.addAll(resultList);
               });
    return result;
}
```

На основе данного ArrayList адаптер должен прорисовывать РеасайклерВью фрагмента, но на этом этапе как раз возникает Exception. Как исправить? И о чем он говорит? Retrofit не может отправить запрос? Ретрофит не может распарсить JSON в BaseResponse? Или не может распарсить данные в List (создать из JSON объекты Usage). Кстати, поля класса Usage тоже снабжены аннотациями @SerializedName

Comment: `Content-Type` нужно указывать когда Вы что-то передаёте в запросе, а для указания желаемого типа ответа от сервера используется `Accept`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Content-Type` может быть указан в запросе в случае передачи каких-то данных в теле самого запроса.
В вашем же случае это простой `GET` без каких-либо параметров и соответственно тела, поэтому вероятно Retrofit и выбрасывает это исключение при создании запроса.

Просто удалите `"Content-Type: application/json)"` из заголовка.

Comment: Только теперь приложение выдает другую ошибку :  io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The mapper function returned a null value.

Comment: Это уже из другой оперы (RxJava), задайте новый вопрос.